# Recyclerview android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-recyclerview

I have a RecyclerView implemented in my Apps MainActivity.

I added an adapter to it which uses a layout that contains a radio button. Is it possibile to send the Group-ID of that RadioButton to my MainActivity?
Or is there a way i can set it's Group-ID through the MainActivity instead of the Adapter so that I can do some operation on it?

Comment: Have you tried using an interface?

Comment: Can u shre some code sample I m not gettin interface method

Comment: See my answer below: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52208864/5496177

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use an interface:

```
interface OnItemSelectedListener {
    void onItemSelected(/* put whatever parameters you want here */);
}
```

And then add that as a parameter for your adapter's constructor:

```
public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyViewHolder> {
    private OnItemSelectedListener listener;

    public MyAdapter(OnItemSelectedListener listener) {
        this.listener = listener;
    }

    //call listener.onItemSelected(your, parameters); whenever needed
}
```

In your Activity, you can either use

```
new MyAdapter(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(your, parameters) {
        //do whatever
    }
}
```

or implement that interface in your Activity:

```
public class WhateverActivity extends Activity implements OnItemSelectedListener {
    //...

    public void onItemSelected(your, parameters) {
        //do whatever
    }
}
```

Comment: interface OnItemSelectedListener {
    void onItemSelected(/* put whatever parameters you want here */);
}     where in which activity to add this code

Comment: You can put it in whatever class you want, even a new one. Just make sure it's public if you put it inside another class.

Answer (score 0):

You can, but you should'nt.
Data must be bind by the RecyclerView, at the onBindViewHolder you create a listener that yes can notify the main activity from the event. If the button to fire the listener is outside the itemviews of the RecyclerView then you can simply get all data from the adapter and check it updated status.

Comment: Radio button is inside recycler view. How I can pass selected radio button value to mainactivity

Comment: When you click RadioButton it will update the value of its position inside the adapter, when you need the info you get all data from adapter (that will be already updated)

Answer (score 0):

If one really need to do some activity with the radio button id which is of a RecyclerView item, then one can use CallBack method to pass the id to the activity.I think this concept will be helpful to your problem.But one should keep in mind that RecyclerView item should be binded in onBindViewHolder in the adapter.You can also do your activity with the Radio Button id on the Binder of your Adapter class.

The listener is in the following,

```
public interface GetRadioIdListener {
    void onGetRadioId(int id);
   }
```

Declare and Initialize the listener to your RecyclerView.Adapter class like this -

```
private GetRadioIdListener idListener;

idListener = (GetRadioIdListener) context;
```

Perform click function on the RadioButton and get the RadioButton id.Thereafter just call the method like this -

```
idListener.onGetRadioId(radioId);
```

I think this will be helpful.

Comment: Yes I want that. Can u share some code how to access in main activity the id of selected radio button

Comment: interface OnItemSelectedListener {
    void onItemSelected(/* put whatever parameters you want here */);
}

Comment: The listener is in the following,

public interface GetRadioIdListener {
    void onGetRadioId(int id);
   }

Declare and Initialize the listener to your RecyclerView.Adapter class like this -

private GetRadioIdListener idListener;

idListener = (GetRadioIdListener) context;

Perform click function on the RadioButton and get the RadioButton id.Thereafter just call the method like this -

idListener.onGetRadioId(radioId);

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do this in different way:

First one is using `content` of MainActivity. For e.g.

When you are creating the object of the `Adapter` into the `MainActivity` Just pass the `context` to the constructor of the `adapter`, like this

This is adapter class

```
private Activity activity;

public FeedAdapter(final Activity activity) {
    this.activity = activity;

} 

 //on radion btn click or item view click 
 radioBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
           @Override
           public void onClick(View v) {
               ((MainActivity)activity).updateSetectedPosition(position);
           }
       });
```

Now you can create a public method in `MainActivity`

```
// By default it's -1 that means in the earlier user not selected anything
private int selectedPos=-1;

public void updateSetectedPosition(final int position){
selectedPos = position;
}
```

The second way is an interface which is already defined above [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52208864/2196176).

Answer (score 0):

You need create an interface to handle the click event in your Adapter.

```
interface OnAdapterClick{
    void OnItemClicked(View v, int position);
}
```

When you have the interface attached between Activity and Adapter

```
private List<Model> entries;
private OnAdapterClick clickListener;

MyAdapter(List<Model> entries, OnAdapterClick  clickListener)
{
    this.entries = entries;
    this.clickListener = clickListener;
}
```

You need handle the click in the viewHolder class

```
class ViewHolderModel extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
private RadioGroup mRadioGroup;


ViewHolderModel(View itemView)
{
    super(itemView);

    this.mRadioGroup = itemView.findViewById(R.id.my_radio_group);
    mRadioGroup.setOnClickListener(this);
}


@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    clickListener.OnItemClicked(view,getAdapterPosition());
}
}
```

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements MyAdapter.OnAdapterClick {

```
MyAdapter entryAdapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    entryAdapter = new MyAdapter(list, this);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(entryAdapter);

}

@Override
public void OnItemClicked(View v, int position) {
    //HERE YOU DO WHATEVER YOU WANT DO WHEN THE CHECKBOX IS CLICKED
}
}
```

I think this help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can user an interface:

```
interface OnItemSelectedListener {
    void onItemSelected(/* here you can put your parameters that you want */);
}
```

And then add a parameter for your adapter's constructor:

```
public class YourAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyViewHolder> {
    private OnItemSelectedListener listener;

    public YourAdapter(OnItemSelectedListener listener) {
        this.listener = listener;
    }

    //call listener.onItemSelected(your, parameters); whenever needed
}
```

In your Activity, you can either use

```
new YourAdapter(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(your, parameters) {
        //do whatever
    }
}
```

or implement that interface in your Activity:

```
public class YourActivity extends Activity implements OnItemSelectedListener {
    //...

    public void onItemSelected(your, parameters) {
        //do whatever
    }
}
```